# Telling an Angular component to reload

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that takes as an **@Input()** a document object and it renders all the replies to that document.  Invoked like this:

```
<app-replies *ngIf="replies" [doc]="doc"></app-replies>
```

So far so good.  Now when the invoking component gets an event that tells it the list of replies has been changed I want to tell the **app-replies** component to re-render the list of replies.

What is the best way to do that? I can think of several possibilities but I haven't found any examples of this situation on the web.  These are:

1. Pass an EventEmitter object into the **app-replies** component then push events into it to trigger reloads.
2. Change the **doc** value passed in to a cloned copy to trigger the framework's change detection.  (No idea if this would actually work).
3. Create an injectable service that provides RxJS **Subject** objects that the component **subscribes** to and have the invoker feed the service.
4. Use **ViewChild()** to reference the component in the invoker and call the **reload()** method in **app-replies** directly.  This has the problem that the child component is the subject of an ***ngIf** clause so the **ViewChild** property doesn't get defined at a predictable time in the component lifecycle.  If there was some way to solve this I would probably prefer this method.

Or perhaps there is some other standard mechanism that I just missed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe #2 to be the best option. If you pass in a new value for `doc`, it should fire the `ngOnChanges` hook

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they think this question is unworthy?   Better yet provide the answer and the source that I should have seen before posting.

Comment: I feel like we might be getting too in-depth here. Is there any reason we couldn't leverage Angular's change detection for this? `*ngFor`'s change detection can be throttled via a comparison function, and the `app-replies` component itself (assuming it's *onPush*) could just have a tell `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in `ngOnChanges`.

Comment: @joh04667 The change detection doesn't cover all cases.  Through experimentation option #2 doesn't work.   I will edit show show my solution shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Would prefer option 2 or option 3.

**option 2:**

If variable doc data type is Array/Object. We can create immutable object using Object.create() /Array.slice().

**option 3:**

If variable doc data type is Number/String. We can create Subject/Behavior/Subject and emit the value using .next(). The emitted value can be accessed using subscribe in the app-replies component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I took the right path on this but I did find a relatively simple solution that seems to work.   The problem with my "option 2" is that setting the variable is not sufficient because the Angular change detection will simply copy the value to the target component, but no methods to load a new set of replies will be called.

So what I did is the following.   The HTML is the same as before:

```
  <app-replies *ngIf="replies" [doc]="replies"></app-replies>
```

Then in the component use a **set** keyword to intercept changes and respond like this:

```
  @Input() set doc(doc: JsonPo) {
    this._doc = doc;
    this.fetchReplies();
  }
  _doc: JsonPo;
```

Now when I set the variable in the invoking component the **fetchReplies()** method is called without me having to reference the component with a **ViewChild** decorator.  (Which has problems in this case).

Further, it isn't necessary to call **fetchReplies()** in **ngOnInit()** anymore because it will be called when the framework builds the component instance, sometime between when the constructor is finished and **ngOnInit()** is called.

I am hoping this will help someone else in this situation.  I haven't seen any similar code examples through searches.